# Перегрузка оператора + для итератора на C++ с исключением out_of_range

Tags: c++, исключения, перегрузка-операторов

Необходимо реализовать перегрузку оператора + для собственного итератора класса.
Проблема в выкидывании ошибки, если мы уйдём за границу итератора.
Вот код:

```
class MatrixRow
{
    private:
    size_t __size;
    double* __data;

    public:
    class Iterator : std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, double>
    {
        private:
        double* __curent;
        
        public:
        Iterator(double* first) : __current(first) {}
        Iterator(const Iterator& ref_iterator) : __current(ref_iterator.__current) {}

        double& operator + (int n)
        {
            if(__curent + n > __data + __size) //Здесь ошибка
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
            }

            return *(__current + n);
        }
    }
    Iterator begin()
    {
        return Iterator(__data);
    }
    Iterator end()
    {
        return Iterator(__data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то по стандарту указатели можно сравнивать только на равенство, иначе UB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да что ж вы то `__current`, то `__curent` пишете, да еще и используете имя с двумя подчерками впереди...

Но в данном случае это к делу не относится. Проблема в том, что `__current` — член `Iterator`, а `__data` и `__size` — члены совсем другого класса (пусть даже охватывающего), и как получить к ним доступ (грубо — где указан *объект*, которому они принадлежат?), компилятор не знает.

Вложенность класса не означает какую-либо связь объектов. Объект итератора должен быть связан с объектом контейнера, если он для него пишется.

Кстати, VC++ выдает вот такое предупреждение:

> warning C4996: 'std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,double,ptrdiff_t,double *,double &>': warning STL4015: The std::iterator class template (used as a base class to provide typedefs) is deprecated in C++17. (The  header is NOT deprecated.) The C++ Standard has never required user-defined iterators to derive from std::iterator. To fix this warning, stop deriving from std::iterator and start providing publicly accessible typedefs named iterator_category, value_type, difference_type, pointer, and reference. Note that value_type is required to be non-const, even for constant iterators. You can define _SILENCE_CXX17_ITERATOR_BASE_CLASS_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.

но оно в полной мере ни при чем, просто для информации.

Comment: Извиняюсь, писал впопыхах как пример, ничего не успел толковее придумать как это. А писать `__` перед приватными членами - старая привычка.

Comment: В С++ это плохая привычка...

Comment: Что же касается связи. Каким образом её добиться? Даже fiend не особо помогает в этой ситуации. И, что ещё хуже, перегрузка сравнения `<` по-моему не определена для указателей, но её нужно осуществить....

Comment: Передаете в конструктор, например, ссылку на объект, для которого должен работать этот итератор, и сохраняете ее в члене класса `Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Идея Harry:

```
class MatrixRow
{
    private:
    size_t __size;
    double* __data;

    public:
    class Iterator : std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, double>
    {
        private:
        double* __current;
        double* __last;
        
        public:
        Iterator(MatrixRow& matrixRow) : __current(matrixRow.__data), __last(matrixRow.__data + matrixRow.__size) {}
        Iterator(const Iterator& ref_iterator) : __current(ref_iterator.__current) {}

        double& operator + (int n)
        {
            if(__current + n > __last)
            {
                throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
            }

            return *(__current + n);
        }
    }
    Iterator begin()
    {
        return Iterator(__data);
    }
    Iterator end()
    {
        return Iterator(__data);
    }
}
```